# Cat command fails to concatenate files horizontally

Tags: unix

I'm trying to concatenate horizontally around 1000 files composed by a single column each one, to one single file. Since all the files that have to be concatenated are named: `myfile1.txt`, `myfile2.txt`, `myfile3.txt`, ..., I used the following string:

```
cat $myfile*.txt > myoutput.txt
```

Unfortunately, the files are concatenated vertically.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: >> is meant to concatenate vertically, you should try with an other command (I'm not really sure how to do it in a shell, I would make a script in an other programing language)
cat does not do any concatenation, it just output the files.

Comment: The title is not fair, `cat` is meant to concatenate the contents of files consecutively, what you want is to interleave the contents. That's not what `cat` promises to do.

Comment: Use `paste file1 file2 file3...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) command is supposed to concatenate files vertically; it would be broken if it did otherwise. (It would be possible to write a variant of `cat` with a non-standard option to direct it to change its behaviour and do horizontal concatenation, but why bother?).

The command designed to paste (concatenate) files horizontally is [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
paste myfile*.txt
```

By default, the lines from each file will be separated by tabs; you can control that and various other aspects of the behaviour of `paste` with command line options.

If you have a thousand files and each line in each file contains, say, 10 characters, then your output file will have lines that are 10 KiB or more long.  Be aware that POSIX does not mandate that utilities (commands) support such long lines, though the best will. (The minimum value for `LINE_MAX` is 2048.)  GNU does require support for indefinitely long lines, but you should be careful to check that whatever you use to process the output of the paste command will work.

Indeed, with 1000 files, you might have to worry about the per-process file descriptor limit.  Use `ulimit -n` (or `ulimit -a`) to find the limit on the number of files a single process can have open.  If it is 256, you may need to increase it.  You'll end up investigating 'hard limits' and 'soft limits' (`ulimit -H -a` and `ulimit -S -a`).

(Note that `cat $myfile*.txt` gives a different list of files from `cat myfile*.txt` unless the variable assignment `myfile=myfile` was done first.)